# Is preinstalled application update work from google play store?

Tags: android

I have an application and my company installs this application in the device and then sell it to customers.

Later on, when I host new version of the same application in Google Play store, whether Google Play store will be able to notify  users that an updated  version of the application is available?

And whether an application can be updated from Google Play store?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to update pre-installed APK apps through Google Play Store. The app needs to have the same package name. Refer to this [Android Developer support article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en), particularly the "Updating system apps" section

> The user’s system apps (including any pre-loaded apps) are shown in
>   the My Apps section of the user's device in the Google Play store as
>   soon as an application with the same package name is uploaded to the
>   Google Play Developer Console, even if the application is unpublished

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Regardless of the method used to install the app (pre-installed, via direct APK, in debug from a computer, ...), if the Play Store has an app with the same package name, the same certificate and a higher version code, it will trigger the update.